# Issue with React app and Service Worker when using Google OAuth2 login

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker

I have added a Service Worker in my React app for caching, and in the Chrome browser, I have activated the 'Update on reload' option within the service workers settings. The app utilizes OAuth2 for Google account login through Passport.js. After a successful login, the backend redirects the user to the '/auth/success' page.

However, when the **"Update on reload" option is enabled** in Chrome, the app reloads again upon opening, and instead of navigating to "/auth/success," it redirects the user to the home page ("/").

In my React app, a complete reload triggers a request to "/getuser," which checks for a user. If the user is found, it takes the user to the home page. when I **uncheck the update on reload** option it works as expected after login it properly redirects to the "auth/success" page.

When using a local strategy for login, the app redirects to the "/auth/success" page seamlessly. The issue only arises when logging in with Google because the local strategy doesn't leave the app and open in a new window, unlike what happens when using Google login.

How to tackle this problem and ensure that after a successful Google OAuth2 login, the app correctly redirects the user to the "/auth/success" page, even with the "Update on reload" option enabled in Chrome?